# Pixel correlation / similarity in an image Python

Tags: python, image, correlation, cross-correlation

I am new in Python.

I have an image of size 8*8, and when flattened = 64. Is there any function that measures the correlation between the pixel i and all the other pixels in this image ?

So at the end I want to plot a 64*64 matrix of correlation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Correlation is a measure to evaluate mutual relationship or connection between two or more things, usually vectors, not single point. Pixel is a single point with a single value. So, in your case, I would subtract pixel value form each pixel value of the image, looking at the difference in this case.

Comment: For example, take the pixel of index 30 in that image of size 64, then you would compare its value with any other pixel in that image, but the only thing you gain from that is the mere difference.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation in the context of just 1 image makes no sense. I guess (or I am almost certain) that the question arose from a misunderstood course question where it is about many images and not just one.
That is why I am just answering here for this new understanding of the question even though the exact question is different.

*Example of 2 images:*

As soon as you take the pixel of index 30 of 2 images instead of just 1 imgage, and then compare them with pixel of index 20, you can compare the 2 values each of those 2 images and only then the correlation of (2 x index 20, 2 x index 30) makes sense.

In that case, you would simply loop over all 64 index columns of the 2 images (number of images = number of rows), apply the Python corr function as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns), and add the results up in a vector of size 64. Mind that there are cases when the variance of the index column is 0, then you should add a 0 to the result vector instead of applying the corr function.