# How to calculate correlation between binary variables in python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation

Two binary variables (x and y) form two columns for a number of dates in a pandas Dataframe. I want to calculate a correlation score between x and y that quantifies how correlated x=1 is with y=1 ( x=0 with y=0).

1. What definition of correlation is appropriate?
2. Is there a built in function?

   ---

   | day |  _x |  _ y|

   ```
   0  | 1 | 1

   1  | 1 | 0

   2  | 0 | 0

   3  | 1 | 1
   ```

Explanation: These are two categoricals. say, x = had eggs for breakfast (0 or 1) and y = got a headache (0 or 1). And there data from several days for both x and y I'm trying to see how 'strongly correlated' having an eggs and having a headache are. I understand that Pearson's correlation is not applicable here. What could be used?

Comment: If these variables are categorical then you cannot calculate correlations.

Comment: `df.x.corr(df.y)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

Comment: `these are binary variables` is 1 > 0 and 0 < 1 for both x and y, or have you encoded two categories as 0 and 1? if the latter, you cannot perform correlation, but you can fit a classification algorithm of some sort and read its parameters after fitting.

Comment: These are two categoricals. say,  x = had eggs for breakfast (0 or 1) and y = got a headache (0 or 1).  And there data from several days for both x and y
I'm trying to see how 'strongly correlated' having an eggs and having a headache are.  I understand that pearson's correlation is not applicable here. What could be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correlation metric to use in this case is Pearson's rho. Defined for two binary variables, it is also known as Pearson's correlation coeffecient.

```
rho = (n11*n00 -  n10*n01)/sqrt(n11.n10.n01.n00)
where 
n11 (n00) = number of rows with x=1(0) and y=1(0) etc.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of "phik" correlation here.

```
import phik
df_corr = df.phik_matrix()
```