# Finding correlation of dataset with multilevel column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my part of my data set.

```
Country              Australia                        Belgium
                                      gdp       wage                 gdp       wage
2006-01-01 00:00:00    745,522,000,000.00  23,826.64  409,813,000,000.00  20,228.74
2007-01-01 00:00:00    851,963,000,000.00  24,616.84  471,821,000,000.00  20,486.16
2008-01-01 00:00:00  1,052,580,000,000.00  24,185.70  518,626,000,000.00  20,588.93
2009-01-01 00:00:00    926,448,000,000.00  24,496.84  484,553,000,000.00  21,284.21
2010-01-01 00:00:00  1,144,260,000,000.00  24,373.76  483,548,000,000.00  20,967.05
```

I would like to find the correlation of the column 'gdp' and the column 'wage' for both countries.

I have tried using,

```
df.corr()
```

but the output came out as an empty result.

The expected output can be as such:

```
  Country    Correlation
Australia            1.0
  Belgium           0.98
```

(The value of the correlation is not accurate. This is shown for illustration only.)

What are the codes that I can run to achieve this result?

Edit:
Executing the line

print(df.columns)

resulted in such output

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Australia', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Costa Rica', 'Czech Republic', 'Estonia', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Japan', 'Korea', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Mexico', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Russian Federation', 'Slovak Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Turkey', 'United Kingdom', 'United States'], ['gdp', 'wage']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=['Country', None])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

Comment: I have went through this question and the form of data frame is different from mine.

Comment: Agree. However, your use of `df.corr()` was completely off and the link provides the proper implementation. Only thing missing is how to call your multiindex columns, which is easier to solve :)

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert columns to numeric with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and cast to `float` and then select levels by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with [`DataFrame.corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) for correlation:

```
#if create DataFrame from file
#df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1], thousands=',')

df = df.replace(',','', regex=True).astype(float)
s = df.xs('gdp', axis=1, level=1).corrwith(df.xs('wage', axis=1, level=1))
print (s)
Australia    0.325915
Belgium      0.521564
dtype: float64
```

Last for DataFrame add `reset_index`:

```
df1 = s.reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Country','Correlation']
print (df1)
     Country  Correlation
0  Australia     0.325915
1    Belgium     0.521564
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.xs('gdp', axis=1, level=1))
                        Australia       Belgium
2006-01-01 00:00:00  7.455220e+11  4.098130e+11
2007-01-01 00:00:00  8.519630e+11  4.718210e+11
2008-01-01 00:00:00  1.052580e+12  5.186260e+11
2009-01-01 00:00:00  9.264480e+11  4.845530e+11
2010-01-01 00:00:00  1.144260e+12  4.835480e+11
```