# finding a correlation equation between two columns using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the correlation equation of two columns using pandas.

I tried using .corr but it only gives the correlation without the equation. any help?

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file='choclates.xlsm'
data= pd.read_excel(excel_file)
data2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheetname=1)
data9=data2['rating'].corr(data2['cocoa'])
```

answer= -0.1643880204966386

Comment: Try this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns This might solve your problem

Comment: thank you. actually it's the same method i already used. i got the correlation, but i need the equation too.

Answer (score 1):

```
  found an answer, this is my code:
 'x=data2.cocoa
  y=data2.rating
  x2 = np.array(x)
  y2 = np.array(y)
  slope, intercept ,r_value,pvalue,std_err = stats.linregress(x2,y2)
  line= slope*x2+intercept
  plt.plot(x2, line, 'b', label='y={:.2f}x+{:.2f}'.format(slope,intercept))
  plt.ylabel('rating')
  plt.xlabel('cocoa')
  plt.legend(fontsize=14)
  plt.show()`
  thank you for the help
```

Comment: So you were looking for a linear regression. Calling it a correlation equation is unclear, the first thought is that you want to the formula to compute the correlation coefficient, which is what `.corr()` does.

Comment: sorry for that. thank you for you'r help! @HS-nebula