# How do you know when a dataframe column can / should be added to a method's parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In [Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

in answer with

```
Top15['Citable docs per Capita'].corr(Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'])
```

and consulting pandas doc on .corr neither parameters nor example indicate you should put column to be correlated with as a parameter to .corr()
How do you know when and if you should can or should put data frame column reference inside a method like here for .corr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good point... it is quite frustrating that in the [pandas.DataFrame.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) documentation, there's no explanation that the input dataframe must be a 2 column dataframe, nor any discussion on what types those columns ought to be, given the correlation coefficients of choice.  That's the kind of thing you could add as a contribution to the pandas project, and I think it would be valuable.

On the other hand, the question you're asking does have an answer on the [pandas.Series.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html#pandas.Series.corr) documentation.

Comment: Thinking about this again... it could be a 3+ column dataframe, and would return an nxn correlation matrix.  still, even that much detail is not provided.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at pandas.DataFrame.corr for pandas 19.2 since that is what the course requires.  And 19.2 documentation doesn't have the example 24.2  I need to understand better syntax / semantics of pandas python, but will be glad to contribute when I do understand don't see an example in docs in future.