# show prices of products with seaborn using a correlation heatmap

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I would like to show one vertical heatmap using seaborn. Like this example:
[image: target Image example]

My dataset is this: 
[image: dataset of products]

I found one example on google but this is not showing the name of the product, only is showing a rare numbers that I don't know:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product','Price'])
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
sns.heatmap(df[['Precio']].sort_values(by=['Precio'],ascending=False),
            vmin=-1,
            cmap='coolwarm',
            annot=True);
plt.savefig('heatmap.png', dpi=50, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This is the result:
[image: Result image]
I want to show the names of the products and his prices in the correlation heatmap.. I'm ordering it by using the "Precio" or price to get a descendent result

### that's it guys I hope that someone could help me. thanks so much.

Update: 13 jun 2020.

```
df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.title("seaborn correlation heatmap")

sns.heatmap(df[['Precio']].sort_values(by=['Precio'],ascending=False),
   vmin=-1, cmap='coolwarm',
    fmt="0.0f",
    annot=True,
    yticklabels=True,
    xticklabels=["Precio de Producto"]) 
plt.savefig('heatmap.png', dpi=50, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The result was:
[image: image result]
But I can't see the name of the items, instead it, are appearing numbers that don't represent the name of the products according to my dataset..
¿how I can fill the yticklabels?

### thanks so much!

Update #2 13-jun-2020 14:49 pm

I tryed to get the names automatically for yticklabels using df.columns.values,
where df is my dataframe also can be called corr, but i called it "df"
the result was:

[image: result image #2]

I'm getting the names of the columns using yticklabels=df.columns.values,
¿how is possible get the name of the rows of the column 0 of the dataframe for yticklabels?
this is my dataset:
[image: image #6]

**Update #3 Fixed Solution: 13-jun-2020 16:32 pm**
first sort the dataframe in order descending according with the column "Precio"

```
df2 = df.nlargest(4, 'Precio')
```

where: 4 is the number of items.
this return a dataframe:

```
        Nombre  Precio
1  Computadora    1050
2    Impresora     490
0     Telefono     200
3         Mesa     120
```

as we can see all the products also are sorted with his respective price:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.title("seaborn correlation heatmap")

sns.heatmap(df[['Precio']].sort_values(by=['Precio'],ascending=False),
   vmin=-1, cmap='coolwarm',
    fmt="0.0f",
    annot=True,
    yticklabels=c['Nombre'], #yticklabels=df.columns.values->puede ser "auto", "True/False"
    xticklabels=["Precio de Producto"]) 
plt.savefig('heatmap.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: finish image]

Comment: You can use the format="0.0f" in the heatmap to see the values in understandable format. you can add the xlabel, yalbel and title using plt.xlabel("X axis") plt.ylabel("Y axis") plt.title("Title"). You can also use ticklabels inside the heatmap sns.heatmap(df[['Precio']].sort_values(by=['Precio'],ascending=False), vmin=-1, cmap='coolwarm', fmt="0.0f" annot=True, yticklabels=["label1"],xticklabels=["L1", "L2","L3", "L4" ]) 
And for the using correlation, here is a helpful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns

Comment: Hello guys HArdRese7 and JohanC I fixed the numbers but now I can´t see the labels of the productos, what should I do? ¿how I can fill the yticklabels? I updated the post.. thanks so much.

Comment: The comment by HArdRese7 suggests using the yticklabels to display the name. Does that work for you? Including the name into the annotation label doesn't work automatically.

Comment: Hello JohanC, yes it works. e.g I did yticklabels=['product1','producto2'], and works but i want to get those values from the dataframe "df" automatically.¿is possible? how we can do it..

Comment: Please see my Update #2 13-jun-2020 14:49 pm in the post

Comment: I fixed it, first sorting the two columns by the column of "Precio/Price"                               
c = df.nlargest(4, 'Precio') this will return a dataframe the in yticklabels=c['Nombre'] of this way I have in the prices in descending order with his respective product. 4 is the number of items.. instead of I should put on there the lenght of the dataframe. but ok now works.