# How to find correlation between two categorical variable num_chicken_pox and how many time vaccine given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The problem is how to find out the correlation between two categorical [series] items?
the situation is like that i have to find out the correlation between HAVING_CPOX and NUM_VECILLA_veccine
Given among children
the main catch is that in HAVING CPOX COLUMNS have 4 unique value

- 1-Having cpox
- 2-not having cpox
- 99- may be NULL
- 7 i don't know

in `df['P_NUMVRC']` : unique value is `[1, 2, 3, 0, Nan,]`
two different distinct series SO how do find put them together and find the correlation
I use value_counts for having frequency of each?

- 1    13781
- 2      213
- 3        1
- Name: P_NUMVRC, dtype: int64
  For having_cpox columns

> 2     27955

> 1       402

> 77      105

> 99        3
> Name: HAD_CPOX, dtype: int64

the requirement is like this

A positive correlation (e.g., corr > 0) means that an increase in had _ch
ickenpox_column (which means more no’s) would also increase the values of
um_chickenpox_vaccine_column (which means more doses of vaccine). If there
is a negative correlation (e.g., corr < 0), it indicates that having had
chickenpox is related to an increase in the number of vaccine doses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

Comment: No, i tried that already

Comment: Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. If relevant, plot images are okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is using `np.corrcoef`. It receives two (in your case - 1 dimensional) arrays, and returns the Pearson Correlation (for more details see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).
So basically:

```
valid_df = df.query('HAVING_CPOX < 3')
valid_df['HAVING_CPOX'].apply(lambda x: x == 1, inplace=True)
corr = np.corrcoef(valid_df['HAVING_CPOX'], valid_df['P_NUMVRC'])
```

What I did is first get rid of the 99's and 7's since you can't really rely on those. Then I changed the HAVING_CPOX to be binary (0 is "has no cpox" and 1 is "has cpox"), so that the correlation makes sense. Then I used corrcoef from numpy's implementation.

Comment: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace' this line pop up every_time i run the program as you said, But , if i remove the inplace it gives me the BOOLEAN values of series, How do i apply the boolen value into correlation, ANd alternatively if i  give the code like

Comment: df['HAD_C']  =df[df['HAD_C'] == 1 ].HAD_C but it gives me the error and give me a caveat that a copy sth can not be modified and recommend me to see py document

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
def corr_chickenpox():
     import pandas as pd
     import scipy.stats as stats
     df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
     dfi=df[["HAD_CPOX","P_NUMVRC"]].copy().dropna()
     dfnew=dfi[dfi["HAD_CPOX"]<=2]
     corr, pval = stats.pearsonr(
             dfnew["HAD_CPOX"], dfnew["P_NUMVRC"]
         )
     return corr
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please validate your response with input given.