# Use python to find best fit averages for multiple factos

Tags: python, modeling

this isn't a super specific question, but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.
Essentially I have a list of json data that looks like this:

```
[
    {"name":"Alex",
"Homework 1 grade":"98",
"Homework 2 grade":"48",
"Homework 3 grade":"38",
"Final grade":"94",
"Minutes spoken":"38",
"pass/fail":"Pass"},

{"name":"Tommy",
"Homework 1 grade":"38",
"Homework 2 grade":"53",
"Homework 3 grade":"92",
"Final grade":"47",
"Minutes spoken":"138",
"pass/fail":"Fail"},
]
```

This goes on for thousands of "students" and I was wondering how I could use python to figure out how to map the formula for pass fail. (Ie: how could I figure out that "minutes spoken" contributed to 25% of your chances of pass/failing and "final grade" contributed to 30% of your chances of pass/failing)

Sorry its such a vague question, but I was wondering if anyone knew a starting point where I could further learn how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What I understood is that you want to know the contribution of the two variables or features "minutes spoken", "final grade" to the "pass/fail" label.

As a start, you can try computing correlation.

From a simple googling, we discover that the statistical relationship between two variables is referred to as their correlation. A correlation could be positive, meaning both variables move in the same direction, or negative, meaning that when one variable's value increases, the other variables' values decrease. And when it is close to zero, the increase/decrease of one variable value does not influence the other generally.

Use the Python Library Pandas to transform your JSON data into a DataFrame and then compute the Correlation between each variable and the label.

Check out this thread: [Use .corr to get the correlation between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns)

Comment: Thank you for all that! I'll check all that out.