# Python Pandas pandas correlation one column vs all

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm trying to get the correlation between a single column and the rest of the numerical columns of the dataframe, but I'm stuck.

I'm trying with this:

```
corr = IM['imdb_score'].corr(IM)
```

But I get the error

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

which I assume is because I'm trying to find a correlation between a vector (my `imdb_score` column) with the dataframe of several columns.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient method it to use [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html).

Example:

```
df.corrwith(df['A'])
```

Setup of example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

#    A  B  C  D  E
# 0  7  2  0  0  0
# 1  4  4  1  7  2
# 2  6  2  0  6  6
# 3  9  8  0  2  1
# 4  6  0  9  7  7
```

output:

```
A    1.000000
B    0.526317
C   -0.209734
D   -0.720400
E   -0.326986
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can you just use `.corr` which [returns all correlations between all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580124/1534017) and then select just the column you are interested in.

So, something like

```
IM.corr()['imbd_score']
```

should work.

Comment: This is inefficient, as many computations will be thrown away. Rather use `corrwith` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479829/16343464)).

Comment: Thanks @mozway, also upvoted you answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calculating all correlations and keeping the ones of interest, it can be computationally more efficient to compute the subset of interesting correlations:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['a'] = range(10)
df['b'] = range(10)
df['c'] = range(10)

pd.DataFrame([[c, df['a'].corr(df[c])] for c in df.columns if c!='a'], columns=['var', 'corr'])
```