# How to apply a function pairwise on rows in a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, row

I want something like this:
df.groupby("A")["B"].diff()

But instead of diff(), I want be able to compute if the two rows are different or identical, and return 1 if the current row is different from the previous, and 0 if it is identical.

Moreover, I really would like to use a custom function instead of diff(), so that I can do general pairwise row operations.

I tried using .rolling(2) and .apply() at different places, but I just can not get it to work.

Edit:

Each row in the dataset is a packet.

The first row in the dataset is the first recorded packet, and the last row is the last recorded packet, i.e., they are ordered by time.

One of the features(columns) is called "ID", and several packets have the same ID.
Another column is called "data", its values are 64 bit binary values (strings), i.e., 001011010011001.....10010 (length 64).

I want to create two new features(columns):

Compare the "data" field of the current packet with the data field of the *previous* packet with the Same ID, and compute:

1. If they are different (1 or 0)
2. How different (a figure between 0 and 1)

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput? Do you need working in `Series` or DataFrame with columns `A, B` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have one column "ID" (not index, and not unique for each row, rows are data packets), and I want to calculate if the last packet with the same ID has had its payload change or not. Then create a new feature "data_changed" that is 1 if the data changed since last packet, and 0 if it has not changed.

Next problem: comparing the payload with the previous packet, computing pearson correlation on the payload to see How Much it changed.

Comment: @Arnau look at the comment above. That is why I use groupby, in order to compute on all rows with the same ID. I do df.groupby("ID")["payload"], sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df["dc"] = df.groupby("ID")["data"].shift().ne(df['data']).astype(int)
```

EDIT: for correlation between 2 Series use:

```
df["dc"] = df['data'].corr(df.groupby("ID")["data"].shift())
```

Comment: Thanks this works! If I want to compute correlation between the two rows instead of just checking equality then?

Comment: @HampusLundberg - I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580124/2901002) solution - and add to answer.

Comment: thanks, but that is not exactly what I was looking for with the correlation. I am not looking for the correlation between the series, but the correlation between the values in one series against the other.

Comment: @HampusLundberg - one series is `df['data']`, another is `df.groupby("ID")["data"].shift()`

Comment: I edited my original post. It is very difficult for me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think it is best if you forgo using the grouby and shift instead:

```
equal_index = (df == df.shift(1))[X].all(axis=1)
```

where X is a list of columns you want to be identic. Then you can create your own grouper by

```
my_grouper = (~equal_index).cumsum()
```

and use it together with agg to aggregate with whatever function you wish

```
df.groupby(my_grouper).agg({'B':f})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it myself with

```
def create_dc(df: pd.DataFrame):
    dc = df.groupby("ID")["data"].apply(lambda x: x != x.shift(1)).astype(int)
    dc.fillna(1, inplace=True)
    df["dc"] = dc
```

this does what I want.
Thank you @Arnau for inspiring me to use .shift()!