# Heatmap from columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I try to generate a heatmap from a pandas dataframe by days and hours of the day (X-> days, Y->hours).
The result should be something like this:

[image]

the data source is a table in postgres:

```
   id    |       created_at       
---------+------------------------
 2558145 | 2017-03-02 11:31:15+01
 2558146 | 2017-03-02 11:31:46+01
 2558147 | 2017-03-02 11:32:28+01
 2558148 | 2017-03-02 11:32:57+01
....
```

here is my code the regroup the data by hour.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/bla')
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_sql_query("""
SELECT created_at, 1 as print
FROM foo
WHERE created_at > '2017-02-01'
AND created_at < '2017-03-01'""", con=engine)

df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df.index = df['created_at']

df = df.resample('H')['print'].sum()
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(df.head())

created_at
2017-02-01 07:00:00+00:00      1.0
2017-02-01 08:00:00+00:00    152.0
2017-02-01 09:00:00+00:00    101.0
2017-02-01 10:00:00+00:00     92.0
2017-02-01 11:00:00+00:00    184.0
Freq: H, Name: print, dtype: float64
```

The result looks fine but I can not figure out how to plot this dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a heatmap from pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788626/how-to-plot-a-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I guess it's not a direct duplicate because in the linked question the data is already in 2D, while here we have single columns which first needs to be transfered to a 2D array - and this may be the step the questioner has problems with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A heatmap is a two dimensional plot, which maps x and y pairs to a value. This means that the input to the heatmap must be a 2D array.

Here you would want to have the columns of the array denote days and the rows to denote the hours. As a first step we would need to have days and hours in two different columns of the dataframe. One could then reshape those columns to 2D arrays, which would require to know how many days and hours there are. If would also require that there is actually an entry for each day/hour pair.
Without this restriction we can alternatively use a `pivot_table` to aggregate the values in a table. This is shown in the following solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe with datetime as index and aggregated (frequency) values
date = pd.date_range('2017-02-23', periods=10*12, freq='2h')
freq = np.random.poisson(lam=2, size=(len(date)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"freq":freq}, index=date)

# add a column hours and days
df["hours"] = df.index.hour
df["days"] = df.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%d'))     
# create pivot table, days will be columns, hours will be rows
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, values="freq",index=["hours"], columns=["days"], fill_value=0)
#plot pivot table as heatmap using seaborn
ax = sns.heatmap(piv, square=True)
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

For plotting you may also use a matplotlib imshow plot as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(piv, cmap="Greens")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

ax.set_xticks(range(len(piv.columns)))
ax.set_yticks(range(len(piv.index)))
ax.set_xticklabels(piv.columns, rotation=90)
ax.set_yticklabels(piv.index)
ax.set_xlabel("Days")
ax.set_ylabel("Hours")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another simple but very useful technique. We could use the `.corr()` function of pandas dataframe and see the correlation values as follows:
[image]

Now if we use `x.corr()`, the result is as follows:

[image]

Finally, we can plot that correlation matrix using the `seaborn` library as follows, using `sns.heatmap(x.corr(), annot=True)`:

[image]

So we can use **`sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)`**. `annot=True` helps to annotate the heatmap with the correlation values.